# Picker Places from Google Maps to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, google-maps, google-places-api

I need put names of highlights from Picker Place from Google Maps SDK to my own TableView. It should be order by distance from center place. I used framework but I see automaticly generated map with picker places and table below.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.788204, -122.411937);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001,
                                                              center.longitude + 0.001);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001,
                                                              center.longitude - 0.001);
GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                     coordinate:southWest];
GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
_placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];


[_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `pickPlaceWithCallback` only return one place for you, so if you want to add multiple places, you have to call this method multiple times. You can declare an array to store the places you picked (ex:     `NSMutableArray *placeArray;`) Then in your table view delegate methods, you can use the `placeArray` as the data source.

Comment: Could you give a example code or any info?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlights"?  Do you mean something like the most prominent places in a given viewport?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want to take names places nearby central point (later will be my actually position) and put it to UITableView. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, `pickPlaceWithCallback` only returns a single place that the user picked.

If you're looking for a list of places that the user is likely at right now, then [`currentPlaceWithCallback`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/current-place#get-current) will work well for you.

However if you need a list of results centered around an arbitrary location, unfortunately the iOS Places API doesn't offer a way to do that.