# Advice about structuring data in Swift using TableView and mapping on GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, swift, database, uitableview, google-maps

I would like to get some advice. I am in the process of making an application where ideally a user can scan through a list of places, see some detail about the place (like name, perhaps some pictures) and be able to select the places they want and save it on a map.

For this I wanted to use Google API. I have created a tabbed application and in one tab I have the GoogleMaps and in another TableView which follows through onto a DetailTableView. My question is firstly, is it possible to link between tabs where upon selection of a cell by the user in Tableview would automatically map the place onto the GoogleMaps tab? Secondly, is there any advice about how to approach this? And how this type of database should be stored/structured? It would have to be a database which will allow access to be updated as well as the user to contribute perhaps.

In the initial table view I would probably just want the name of places whereas the Detailed table view should give more details such as Address, website link (if place is a business), opening times, related pictures etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off checking [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_results_controller) as it deals with names of places and some details about them. It also has sample codes on displaying Table Views.

If you want additional code samples, check out [Layering a table view and a google map view iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862022/layering-a-table-view-and-a-google-map-view-ios-swift) and [Picker Places from Google Maps to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657813/picker-places-from-google-maps-to-uitableview).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. So I've followed the Place Autocomplete guidelines and have the search autocomplete working and so far all it does is you start typing in a name and it comes up with suggestions and whatever I click, it comes out with a marker on the place. However I'm stuck on two things- firstly, is it possible to give an option to the user to save this location onto the map? (like have that marker there permanently until the user deletes it). And secondly, how do I actually extract the details from the place selected and get it to show somewhere? (like a tableview)